# creating a new object triggers an exception c#

Tags: c#, class, exception

When I create a new thing from the MyClass class it triggers an exception.

```
namespace class_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MyClass thing = new MyClass();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = thing.x.ToString();
        thing.x++;
    }
}
```

code for the class:

```
namespace debugging_class
{
    class MyClass : Form1
    {
        public int x = 100;
    }
}
```

By testing I found out that the `: Form1` from the class code is the issue. I am using that because I want to access Form1 objects in the class. Is there any way to do that without using `: Form1`?

Comment: What is the exception and what line is firing it?

Comment: System.StackOverflowException on the line with 
`MyClass thing = new MyClass();`

Comment: That exception is common in cases of infinite recursion. Are you calling `new MyClass()` inside of `MyClass`'s constructor?

Comment: I don't. All that I have within the constructor is `public in value = 100;`

Comment: Your probably calling it in the constructor of Form1. So creating a new `thing` will call the Form1 constructor again

Comment: Can you post the code for `Form1` and `MyClass`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: When you're debugging and the exception happens, look at the Stack Trace. It'll tell you what's happening. You'll probably see the infinite recursion happening there.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code. Sorry about that @jdphenix

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed one of infinite recursion. When you create a `MyClass` object, it calls the constructor for that class. Because `MyClass` inherits from `Form1` and you haven't specified a default (parameterless) constructor for `MyClass`, it will implicitly call the constructor for `Form1`.

The problem is that you have in your code for `Form1` a class-level variable with a default value. When a class has a field with a default value, those variables will be implicitly set with the given value at the beginning of that object's constructor. So, for example, the code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int i = 5;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        // Just a simple call and that's it
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Will actually compile to something resembling the following:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int i;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        // Assign default values to class instance fields
        i = 5;

        // Execute the rest of the constructor code
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

So here is the problem - your `Form1` class has a `MyClass` field with a default value of `new MyClass()`. That field will be assigned in `Form1`'s constructor. Because `MyClass` inherits from `Form1`, then `Form1`'s constructor will also get called, which will then create a new instance of `MyClass`, which will call the constructor for `Form1` again... You see how this turns into infinite recursion? The constructors of `Form1` and `MyClass` are calling each other back and forth forever and ever (or at least until the program reaches the limit of recursion and throws a StackOverflowException).

The reason that your code runs fine if you remove the default value and instead put the instantiation of the field inside a separate method is because that method won't get called until later in your program. `MyClass`'s constructor will call `Form1`'s constructor and then return, allowing your program to continue on its merry way.

Comment: I get what you are saying but later in my project I want to be able to access an object such as a TextBox from Form1 in MyClass. How should I do that?

Comment: @JohnDoe Why do you need to create `MyClass` in order to do that? Why not just use `Form1`?